# Alexandroff Topology Connectedness and Path-Connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm trying to prove a corollary of the following Lemma.

Lemma 2:

Let $X=\left\{P_{0}, P_{1}, \cdots, P_{n}\right\}$ be a finite set. There exist exactly two Alexandroff topologies on $X$ with the property that exactly all segments of consecutive points $P_{i}, P_{i+1}, \cdots, P_{j}$ with $0 \leq i<j \leq n$ are connected sets. These topologies are

$\begin{aligned} \mathcal{T}_{1}: \quad O P_{i} &=\left\{P_{i}\right\} \text { if } i \text { even, } \\ O P_{i} &=\left\{P_{i-1}, P_{i}, P_{i+1}\right\} \quad \text { if } i \neq 1, n \text { odd }, \\ O P_{1} &=\left\{P_{1}, P_{2}\right\}, \\ O P_{n} &=\left\{P_{n-1}, P_{n}\right\}, \text { if } n \text { odd. } \end{aligned}$

and

$\begin{aligned} \mathcal{T}_{2}: \quad O P_{i} &=\left\{P_{i}\right\} \text { if } i \text { odd, } \\ O P_{i} &=\left\{P_{i-1}, P_{i}, P_{i+1}\right\} \quad \text { if } i \text { even and } i \neq n, n \text { even }, \\ O P_{n} &=\left\{P_{n-1}, P_{n}\right\}, \text { if } n \text { even. } \end{aligned}$

---

Corollary:

If $P_{0}=P_{n}$ then there exists an Alexandroff topology for $X$ such that exactly all segments of consecutive points on the cyclic sequence of points (numbered modulo $n$ ) are connected if and only if $n$ is odd.

I just don't know how to approach this proof. I tried to look at the absurd proof, but I can't get clearly what $n$ being even will get to. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question is formatted nicely, however, you will get better feedback if you provide what you have tried - you will get better feedback.

Comment: Hello @TaylorRendon . I proved the Lemma, but I dont really know where to start on the proof of the Corollary.

Comment: @ArcticChar This question is about a different notion of "Alexandroff space" from the one in metric geometry.

Comment: Maybe look at this [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4148920/4280) too, same class?