# Path-Connected Alexandroff Spaces

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following Lemma.

Lemma 2:

Let $X=\left\{P_{0}, P_{1}, \cdots, P_{n}\right\}$ be a finite set. There exist exactly two Alexandroff topologies on $X$ with the property that exactly all segments of consecutive points $P_{i}, P_{i+1}, \cdots, P_{j}$ with $0 \leq i<j \leq n$ are connected sets. These topologies are

$\begin{aligned} \mathcal{T}_{1}: \quad O P_{i} &=\left\{P_{i}\right\} \text { if } i \text { even, } \\ O P_{i} &=\left\{P_{i-1}, P_{i}, P_{i+1}\right\} \quad \text { if } i \neq 1, n \text { odd }, \\ O P_{1} &=\left\{P_{1}, P_{2}\right\}, \\ O P_{n} &=\left\{P_{n-1}, P_{n}\right\}, \text { if } n \text { odd. } \end{aligned}$

and

$\begin{aligned} \mathcal{T}_{2}: \quad O P_{i} &=\left\{P_{i}\right\} \text { if } i \text { odd, } \\ O P_{i} &=\left\{P_{i-1}, P_{i}, P_{i+1}\right\} \quad \text { if } i \text { even and } i \neq n, n \text { even }, \\ O P_{n} &=\left\{P_{n-1}, P_{n}\right\}, \text { if } n \text { even. } \end{aligned}$

I divided the proof into 3 steps.

First step. We will prove that $OP_i$ does not contain any point $P_k$ with $k \neq i − 1, i, i + 1$.

Second Step. |OP_i| = 2 implies that $i=1$ or $i=n$

Third Step. We proved the remaining posibilites. That is $OP_i = \{P_i\}$ or $OP_i = \{P_{i-1},P_i, P_{i+1}\}$

I already prove 1 and 3, the third one using the second step. Nevertheless, I couldn't prove the second one. I did the following by absurd, but I don't know if its good as I didn't used the fact that $i \neq 1$ and $i \neq n$.

Second Step Proof Attempt:

Suppose by absurd that $OP_i = \{P_i, P_{i+1} \}$ with $i \neq 1$ and $i \neq n$.
Observe that $P_i \in OP_{i-1}$, because if not, $\{P_{i-1}, P_i\}$ will not be connected, which contradicts the hypothesis. Observe that $P_{i+1} \notin OP_{i-1}$ because  $\{P_{i-1}, P_{i+1}\}$ is not connected, which means that there exists open, not empty, disjoint sets such that $P_{i+1} \in T1$ and $P_{i-1} \in T2$. Because $T_1 \cap T_2 = \emptyset$ then $P_{i+1} \notin T2$ and $P_{i-1} \notin T1$. As $OP_{i-1}$ is the intersection of all the open sets that contain $P_{i-1}$ and $T_2$ is an open set that contains $P_{i-1}$ but not $P_{i+1}$ then $P_{i+1} \notin OP_{i-1}$.
Therefore, $OP_{i-1} \cap OP_{i+1} = \{P_i\}$. Observe that  $OP_{i-1} \cap OP_{i+1}$ is an open set that contains only $P_i$. Note that, being $OP_i$ being the intersection of all the open sets that contain $P_i$, then there is only one point in common for all of these, and that is $P_i$. That is why $OP_i = \{P_i\}$. Then $|OP_i| = 1$, which is a contraiction.

That is why, if $|OP_i|= 2$, then $i=n$ or $i=1$.

---

However, I am not using that neither $i \neq n$ or $i \neq 1$. I don't know if the proof is right.